# Android Material Design support for eclipse

Tags: android

Is it possible to work on material design in eclipse IDE.
When I run the app I'm getting issue to change the app theme to appcomact instead of android:Theme.Material

Comment: Moved to #AS Please .

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I am giving you the solution but I would also recommend you to use Android Studio.

For material design in eclipse do the following steps:
1) Import the Design Folder into your workspace. (Design folder will be in SDK >extras>android>support >design)
Note while importing tic the box showing "copy to workspace"
2) Right click the design project from eclipse and in properties go to android and tic is Library.
3) Now in your project right click go to properties and under library section click on add, and then select design project which u just imported.
You are ready to go.